# Aligning boxes and sizing children

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my `div` boxes work out.

I want the orange boxes to have the same size by expanding the smaller ones to the same height as the biggest one.

I also want to make the one on the second row fit properly, to the left perfectly aligned.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="picture">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="description">A description</div>
</div>

<div class="picture">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="description">A description <br /> Extra line</div>
</div>

<div class="picture">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="description">A description</div>
</div>

<div class="picture">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="description">A description</div>
</div>

<div class="picture">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="description">A description</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.picture {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 5px;

    float: left;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

    background-color: chartreuse;
}

.description {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

JSFiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/PW3GV/1/

**Edit**

The orange boxes can have a varying height. Sometimes it may contain 1 line, 2 lines or 3 lines - so a fixed height is not going to work out

Comment: Here's a special version for you http://jsfiddle.net/PW3GV/5/

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.picture` width to 18.484% as below:

```
.picture {
    width: 18.484%;
    margin: 5px;   
    float: left;
}

.description {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

And add the jQuery script as below:

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    var tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    equalHeight($(".description"));
});
```

See the updated [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vagish/PW3GV/6/).

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VYZEx/

i've just added a single line of code to the css, it will work as long as you don't mind that the orange boxes have a fixed size, in that case change this and you will be done:

```
.description {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There you are [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skL8t/) hope it's what you were aiming for;

```
.picture {
    width: 18.5%;
    margin: 5px;

    float: left;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

    background-color: chartreuse;
}

.description {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.description::-webkit-scrollbar{
   display: none; 
}
```

I kept the description size as it is and instead made it scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `.picture` frame a relative positioning, make the description position relative and place it at the bottom of the `.picture` frame then give it a 100% width to take up the entire container.

```
.picture {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

.description {
    background-color: orange;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PW3GV/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would attempt this using relative positioning for .picture and absolute positioning for .description.

See my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PW3GV/9/

`.picture {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}
.description {
    background-color: orange;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}`